# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm working on a Windows form application wherein I'm adding a background color on runtime. Here's the code:

```
using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                                                                          Color.FromArgb(252, 253, 255),
                                                                          Color.FromArgb(153, 204, 255),
                                                                          LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
```

The problem is when my the application loads, it works perfectly, but the moment I minimize the application and then open it again, it throws me an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Rectangle '{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}' cannot have a width or height equal to 0.

It is happening for **this.ClientRectangle** whose width and height changes to 0.

Please suggest a way to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple sanity check against the members of the rectangle would prevent this.

Comment: I found the solution. Instead of using "this.ClientRectangle", I used "panel.ClientRectangle". It's working fine now. Thanks!